# How to display messages as list in gmail api?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, google-api, gmail-api

I am creating a project where I can read messages of gmail. I am having problem to display list of messages. I've just quickstart sample code of getting labels.

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/js#step_1_set_up_the_sample

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Gmail API Quickstart</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Gmail API Quickstart</p>

    <button id="authorize_button" onclick="handleAuthClick()">Authorize</button>
    <button id="signout_button" onclick="handleSignoutClick()">Sign Out</button>

    <pre id="content" style="white-space: pre-wrap;"></pre>

    <script type="text/javascript">

      const CLIENT_ID = 'XXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com';
      const API_KEY = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';

      const DISCOVERY_DOC = 'https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/gmail/v1/rest';

      const SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly';

      let tokenClient;
      let gapiInited = false;
      let gisInited = false;

      document.getElementById('authorize_button').style.visibility = 'hidden';
      document.getElementById('signout_button').style.visibility = 'hidden';

      function gapiLoaded() {
        gapi.load('client', intializeGapiClient);
      }

      async function intializeGapiClient() {
        await gapi.client.init({
          apiKey: API_KEY,
          discoveryDocs: [DISCOVERY_DOC],
        });
        gapiInited = true;
        maybeEnableButtons();
      }

      function gisLoaded() {
        tokenClient = google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient({
          client_id: CLIENT_ID,
          scope: SCOPES,
          callback: '', // defined later
        });
        gisInited = true;
        maybeEnableButtons();
      }

      function maybeEnableButtons() {
        if (gapiInited && gisInited) {
          document.getElementById('authorize_button').style.visibility = 'visible';
        }
      }

      function handleAuthClick() {
        tokenClient.callback = async (resp) => {
          if (resp.error !== undefined) {
            throw (resp);
          }
          document.getElementById('signout_button').style.visibility = 'visible';
          document.getElementById('authorize_button').innerText = 'Refresh';
          await listLabels();
        };

        if (gapi.client.getToken() === null) {
          tokenClient.requestAccessToken({prompt: 'consent'});
        } else {
          tokenClient.requestAccessToken({prompt: ''});
        }
      }

      function handleSignoutClick() {
        const token = gapi.client.getToken();
        if (token !== null) {
          google.accounts.oauth2.revoke(token.access_token);
          gapi.client.setToken('');
          document.getElementById('content').innerText = '';
          document.getElementById('authorize_button').innerText = 'Authorize';
          document.getElementById('signout_button').style.visibility = 'hidden';
        }
      }

      async function listLabels() {
        let response;
        try {
          response = await gapi.client.gmail.users.labels.list({
            'userId': 'me',
          });
        } catch (err) {
          document.getElementById('content').innerText = err.message;
          return;
        }
        const labels = response.result.labels;
        if (!labels || labels.length == 0) {
          document.getElementById('content').innerText = 'No labels found.';
          return;
        }
        const output = labels.reduce(
            (str, label) => `${str}${label.name}\n`,
            'Labels:\n');
        document.getElementById('content').innerText = output;
      }
    </script>
    <script async defer src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js" onload="gapiLoaded()"></script>
    <script async defer src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" onload="gisLoaded()"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This code is working fine without any errors.
I want to modify this code and get list of messages. But I am just unable to find right method to get list of messages.

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [This](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.labels/list) is the documentation for labels. Compare that with the sample code you have for labels.
2. Then try to follow the same principle for messages. This is the documentation for [messages](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/list). Following bullet 1, the code to get the list of messages might be something like

```
    gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.list({'userId': 'me'});
```

You can work out how to parse the response from the linked documentation

**Update:**

The documentation says

> each message resource contains only an id and a threadId. Additional message details can be fetched using the `messages.get` method.

This means you have to do something like

```
  gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.get({
    'userId': 'me',
    'id' : <message_id>
    });
```

Comment: I just replaced this line of code with `gapi.client.gmail.users.labels.list({'userId': 'me',});`. It is not working. And I am unable to work out on parsing the response. I was hoping a code. In documentation there was something like get messages by it's **id** and **thread**. I want to display at least 10 or 25 messages and having problem do that.

Comment: You need to be more explicit in your reports. Instead of just saying - it is not working, say exactly what is happening e.g. do you get an error? If so, what is the error? Also this assumes that the code you presented for labels already works. If it doesn't work, then you can't be asking for help with messages. You have to first figure out the issue with that labels code.

Comment: Sorry for that I am still a Novice.  I didn't get any errors in that. I want to modify that code so that I can display list of messages. I searched everywhere but still didn't find right method to do it. I want to do it without node js. I searched on stackoverflow but that questions are of another languages or with NodeJs.

Comment: Let me rephrase the question - does the code you have to retrieve labels work? Does it actually return the labels to you? If it doesn't, you should indicate that in your post or ask how to fix that. I say this because if you look at the documentation, the code for labels and messages follow the same format.

Comment: Thanks to you! I got Id's and Thread Id's of messages Without any errors. But now I am just getting Objects having property **id** and **ThreadId**. What should I do next?

Comment: The documentation says - **Note that each message resource contains only an id and a threadId. Additional message details can be fetched using the ```messages.get``` method.**

Comment: I updated my response with sample code

Comment: It worked when I accessed `msg.result.snippet`! 
How should I get  Subject of that message by Id?

Comment: Try and read the documentation first before you ask a question. According to the documentation, output from ```messages.get``` includes a ```payload``` attribute whose value is an object of type ```MessagePart``` which in turn has an attribute ```headers``` and the documentation says this about the headers object - List of headers on this message part. For the top-level message part, representing the entire message payload, it will contain the standard RFC 2822 email headers such as To, From, and Subject.

Comment: documentation was difficult! I read some concepts but couldn't catch it!